# oracle trigger to MySql

Tags: mysql, oracle

Write a trigger that makes new students named 'Friendly' automatically like everyone else in their grade. That is, after the trigger runs, we should have ('Friendly', A) in the Likes table for every other Highschooler A in the same grade as 'Friendly'.

```
create trigger R1
    before insert on Highschooler
    for each row
    when  New.name="Friendly"
    begin
      insert into Likes 
     Select New.ID,ID from Highschooler where grade = New.grade ;
     end;
```

Comment: What is your question here? Why does your title mention oracle and MySQL, however, your tags are `mysql` and `sql-server`? Which RDBMS are you using...? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50064538/edit) your post with a **question** and correct your tags. Thanks.

Comment: Hello this is my first time to use this mysql
And i trying to do create trigger using Sqlyog
I just ask how to convert this trigger to sqlyog ^^

Comment: So, what are you using, MySQL, Oracle, or SQL Server? They are different RDBMS's. Only tag the one(s) you are using (I very much doubt you are using all three). You haven't asked a question either, just posted what looks like a Homework assignment (questions end with a Question Mark (`?`)). SO isn't a website to have your homework done for you, you should be doing that yourself. If you're having difficulty, Users here will be happy to help you, however, post what you've tried, any errors you've received, and also ask a question. We're not doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle trigger code

```
create trigger R1
    before insert on Highschooler
    for each row
    when  New.name="Friendly"
    begin
      insert into Likes 
     Select New.ID,ID from Highschooler where grade = New.grade ;
     end;
```

This MySQL trigger code should behave the same as the Oracle trigger code.

```
delimiter $$;
create trigger R1
    before insert on Highschooler
    for each row
    begin
      if NEW.name = "Friendly" then
       insert into Likes Select New.ID,ID from Highschooler where grade = New.grade ;
      end if;
     end$$
delimiter;
```